# What is the difference between build.sbt and build.scala?

Tags: scala, sbt

I started to learn Scala and almost in every tutorial I see a `build.sbt` file which describes project settings. But now I have installed `giter8` and created a project from template. And generated project from template missed `build.sbt` file, but it have `build.scala` (which seems used for same purposes, but it is more flexible).

So what is the difference between `build.sbt` and `build.scala`?
Which is more preferred and why?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

To give a brief example, this `build.sbt`:

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"
```

is a shorthand notation roughly equivalent to this `project/Build.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object Build extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file(".")).settings(
    name := "hello",
    version := "1.0"      
  )
}
```

The `.sbt` file can also include `val`s, `lazy val`s, and `def`s (but not `object`s and `class`es).

See [the SBT document called ".scala build definition"](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Full-Def.html), particularly the section "Relating build.sbt to Build.scala".

Consider a `.scala` build definition if you're doing something complicated where you want the full expressiveness of Scala.

Comment: On "build.sbt rarely ends up being sufficient", it is true in 0.12 and earlier that once you want to define tasks or multi-module builds, you need .scala files.  This should be addressed in 0.13, where you can now define vals and multiple projects.  You are of course still welcome to start with .scala though.

Comment: SBT documentation on this topic - http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Full-Def.html

Answer (score 33):

Update July 2016 (3 years later)

`Build.scala` is officially deprecated in [sbt 0.13.12](http://notes.implicit.ly/post/147554513094/sbt-01312)

> The `Build` trait is deprecated in favor of the `.sbt` format

[PR 2530](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/2530) implements that deprecation.
"[Appendix: `.scala` build definition](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Full-Def.html)" has been updated.

Answer (score 13):

When `.sbt`s are being compiled, they are before that sort of merged with the `.scala` files inside `project` directory. They can't be used in recursive tasks, that is, you can't customize `sbt` from `sbt`, for example. For more detailed information, consider reading related section is sbt documentation: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html#sbt-vs-scala-definition