# Explanation of SBT build file

Tags: scala, sbt

### Question

Is .sbt file is a in scala or in sbt proprietary language? Please help to decipher the sbt build definition.

```
lazy val root = <--- Instance of the SBT Project object? Why "lazy"? Is "root" the reserved keyword for sbt to identify the project in the build.sbt?
    (project in file("."))  <--- Is this defining a Project object regarding the current directory having the SBT expected project structure?
    .settings(              <--- Is this a scala function call of def settings in the Project object?
        name := "NQueen",
        version := "1.0",
        scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
        mainClass in Compile := Some("NQueen")        
    )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(  <--- libraryDependencies is a reserved keyword of type scala.collection.Seq using which sbt downloads and packages them as part of the output jar?
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0",  <--- Concatenating and creating the full library name including version. I suppose I need to look into respective documentations to find out what to specify. 
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.0"
)

// <--- Please explain what this block does and where I can find the explanations.
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
 case x => MergeStrategy.firs
}
```

### Resources

Please suggest good resources to understand the design, mechanism, how .sbt works. I looked into the SBT getting started and documents but as Scala definition itself, it is difficult to understand. If it is make, ant, or maven, how things get pieced together and the design/mechanism are so much clear, but need to find good documentations or tutorials for SBT.

### References

I looked into the references below trying to understand.

- [SBT: How to get started using the Build.scala file (instead of build.sbt)](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-to-use-build.scala-instead-of-build.sbt)
- [What is the difference between build.sbt and build.scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000103/what-is-the-difference-between-build-sbt-and-build-scala)
- [SBT - Build definition](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Basic-Def.html)
- [SBT Project object](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/Project.html)
- [scala.collection.Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Seq.html)
- [SBT Library dependencies](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Dependencies.html)
- [Spark 2.3 Quick Start](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html)

Comment: You are not the only one that thinks sbt is cryptographic: http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/SowhatswrongwithSBT.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sbt can be really difficult for first time users, and it's ok not to fully understand all of the definitions. It will become clearer over time.

let me first simplify you `build.sbt`. it contains some unnecessary parts, and will be easier to explain without them

```
name := "NQueen"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
mainClass in Compile := Some("NQueen")        

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(  
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0", 
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.0"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
 case x => MergeStrategy.firs
}
```

and for your questions:

> Is .sbt file is a in scala or in sbt proprietary language?

well, it's both.  you can do most scala operations in an `.sbt` file. you can import and use external dependencies, write custom code, etc.. but some things you can't do (define classes for example).
It's also might look as a dedicated different language, but in reality, it's just a DSL written in scala (`:=`, `in`, `%%`, `%` are all function written in scala)

> libraryDependencies is a reserved keyword of type scala.collection.Seq using which sbt downloads and packages them as part of the output jar?

`libraryDependencies` is not a reserved keyword. you can think of it as a way to configure you project.
writing `libraryDependencies := Seq(..)` you basically setting the value of `libraryDependencies`.
But you are right about the meaning. it is a list of dependencies that should be downloaded.

> Concatenating and creating the full library name including version. I suppose I need to look into respective documentations to find out what to specify.

keep in mind that `%%` and `%` are functions. you use those functions to specify what modules should be downloaded and added to the classpath.
you can find many dependencies (and their versions) in mvnrepository.
for example, for spark: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.3.0

> Please explain what this block does and where I can find the explanations.

`assemblyMergeStrategy` is a setting coming from the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin.
that plugin allows you to pack your application into a single jar with all the dependencies.
you can read about the merge strategy here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy