# Can you put SBT code inside a scala script?

Tags: scala, scripting, sbt

I'm sure I've seen a page that shows how to put SBT instructions inside a scala file, instead of build.sbt. The advantage is that everything then lives in a single file, which makes it easier to use Scala as a scripting language.

But I can't now find the example... can anyone help?

BTW, I know about ammonite, but it has limitations compared to SBT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this page of the sbt docs: [Scripts, REPL, and Dependencies](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Scripts.html). There are also some other resources on the topic:

- an example project by Eric Richardson with detailed instructions: [ekrich/sbt-scripting](https://github.com/ekrich/sbt-scripting)
- a post by Eugene Yokota (maintainer of sbt): [scripting with Scala](http://eed3si9n.com/scripting-with-scala) (it's from 2014, so I'm not sure if it's still relevant)
- an example script [gist](https://gist.github.com/SethTisue/3a5a04e5054fc5b75011) by Seth Tisue

Comment: That was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your customize **scala** file under `project/` directory and **import** it in **build.sbt**, like:

```
├── build.sbt
└── project
    └── Settings.scala
```

so you can import it in `build.sbt`:

```
import Settings._
```

Comment: Errr... I'm trying to get everything in a single file! I know it's possible; I've seen an example somewhere on the internet...

Comment: @Mohan, so you mean [Build.scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000103/what-is-the-difference-between-build-sbt-and-build-scala) but it is deprecated.