sbt publish a package with varying dependencies
I have an sbt project which consists of 3 different layer:

base
impl (is a directory which contains many different implementation packages, and each package depends on base)
api (depends on an "impl", could be any of them)

The code in the base and the api package is always the same, the only thing that can change is one of the impls, for instance, I can introduce a new implementation.
Now I want to publish locally the api package depending on each of the implementations, by different names, for instance, one package called api-impl1, api-impl2 and so on.
One thing that I've tried is to do this one by one, which is not really a smart idea. So I was wondering if there's any dynamics to sbt to do this for me

"one by one", do you mean using subprojects/submodules in SBT, declared in the build.sbt? If the project definition is strictly identical you can probably have some kind of loop in the build.sbt.

But I suppose each implementation has different dependencies, otherwise why package them separately? Then I don't see how you can avoid manually declaring them one by one.

@GaëlJ yes, each of them has different dependencies. I have defined the impl projects manually, my concern was regarding the api project. I want to publish the api package based on each of these implementations. I can also share the github link if you wanted to take a closer look.

Sounds weird that an API depends on an implementation, it's usually the opposite but I guess that's a matter of terminology. Anyway, either do it manually: if you did it for the impl modules, why not for api-impl? Or try the "loop": declare a Seq of your impl projects and generate the api-impl ones?

@GaëlJ I see, but the impls are not the implementations of api, those are the implementations of external libraries, the api layer provides a unified syntax for those libraries.


if there's any dynamics to sbt to do this for me

Yes, for example here I'm generating projects using Scala 2.13.0-2.13.13
project/Build.scala
import sbt.*
import Keys.*

object Build extends AutoPlugin {
  override def extraProjects: Seq[Project] = (0 to 13).map(i => {
    val name = s"proj2_13_$i"
    Project(name, file(name))
      .settings(scalaVersion := s"2.13.$i")
  })
}



Thank you for the help. My main concern is regarding "publishing" those packages, not only creating them. I was able to generate the projects using your idea by defining a task.

@AminMal publishLocal publishes all the projects generated

It doesn't, I'm able to generate the api projects, but sbt doesn't recognize them as projects, probably because they're not assigned to values (I'm generating them in build.sbt, not a AutoPlugin, because these api projects need to depend on a specific impl)

@AminMal If sbt doesn't recognize them as projects then this probably means that you didn't generate projects. I'm not sure what you're doing in build.sbt, defining a task etc., please prepare reproduction. Please don't generate projects in build.sbt, try the approach with AutoPlugin like I showed. There is .dependsOn in Project(name, file(name)).settings(...).dependsOn(...).

@AminMal build.sbt supports limited subset of Scala. Build.scala is ordinary Scala.

@AminMal Build.scala was an alternative to build.sbt in sbt 0.13.x https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000103/what-is-the-difference-between-build-sbt-and-build-scala In sbt 1.x it's absent but can be emulated with AutoPlugin.

@AminMal In my example I don't have build.sbt at all.

Ah, yes. I hade made a mistake. I used what you suggested, and regarding the dependency issue that I had (which I wasn't able to make apis depend on a project defined in build.sbt), I used LocalProject to fix it. Thank you for your suggestion!
